# Object Being Placed Above Div Despite Being Behind it?

Tags: css, reactjs

I am working on a React web application and one of the features I am implementing has a "blob" that trails behind the mouse cursor. This blob is blurred by placing another div over it and using backdrop-filter (I was getting concentric circles if I didn't do this method). This works fine. Although, when I go to place another div over the blob object, it appears that the backdrop-filter is also blurring everything else.

Here is my ReactJS code for the Blob:

```
import { useEffect } from "react";

const Blob = () => {
    useEffect(() => {
        const myBlob = document.getElementById("blob");

        if(myBlob) {
            document.body.onpointermove = event => {
                const {clientX, clientY} = event;
        
                myBlob.animate({
                    left: `${clientX - 150}px`,
                    top: `${clientY - 100}px`
                }, {duration: 3000, fill: "forwards"});
            }
        }
    }, [])
    
    
    
    return (
        <div>
            <div id="blob" className="blob"></div>
            <div id="blur" className="blur"></div>
        </div>
        
    );
}

export default Blob;
```

Here is my ReactJS code for the rest of the page:

```
import Blob from "../atoms/trinkets/Blob";
const Home = () => {
    return (
        <div className="return-container">
            <Blob/>
            <div className="block"></div>
        </div>
    )
}


export default Home;
```

Here is my CSS for both:

```
.blob {
    background: linear-gradient(to right, aquamarine, mediumpurple);
    height: 200px;
    width: 300px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    animation: rotate360 20s infinite;
}

.blur {
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 2;
    backdrop-filter: blur(75px);
}

@keyframes rotate360 {
    from {
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }

    to {
        transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}

.block {
    height: 500px;
    width: 500px;
    background-color: pink;
    z-index: 5;
}
```

No matter what I try, the #blur div is placing the backdrop-filter over everything else. I checked Dev Tools to see where everything was being placed and can confirm that the .block div is appearing on top of everything else

Answer (score 0):

#block is not above everything, it is actually most bottom layer

Order of layers you have

1. #blur (Most Above Layer)
2. #blob
3. #block (Most Bottom Layer)

that is means **div#blur** is above everything, and that's ***because*** it is after **div#blob** in DOM, and since both of them has same `position:absolute` so last element will override first one (**div#blur** override **div#blob**)

and your **#blur** has a `z-index: 2` and that's not necessary, because it will be above #blob anyway, because as we said it is after **#blob** in DOM

**div#block** has not `position:absolute` at all, and that's mean it is in last layer (bottom of **div#blur** and **div#blob**)

and since #block has not `position` so it shouldn't take `z-index` property

I think you can look up video or article talking about `Position in CSS` and you will be fine
[FeeCodeCamp Article](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/css-positioning-position-absolute-and-relative/)